# MVC 6 Group Permission Cannot Get Role

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Im converting [ASP.NET Identity 2.0: Implementing Group-Based Permissions Management](http://johnatten.com/2014/08/10/asp-net-identity-2-0-implementing-group-based-permissions-management/) to ASP.NET Core , all is good, but i cannot get the role from groups

heres the code :

ApplicationGroup Entity

```
public sealed class ApplicationGroup
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationGroupRole> ApplicationGroupRoles { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationGroupUser> ApplicationGroupUsers { get; set; }

    public ApplicationGroup()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        ApplicationGroupRoles = new List<ApplicationGroupRole>();
        ApplicationGroupUsers = new List<ApplicationGroupUser>();
    }

}
```

ApplicationGroupRole Entity

```
public class ApplicationGroupRole
{
    public string ApplicationRoleId { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationGroupId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationGroupId")]
    public ApplicationGroup ApplicationGroup { get; set; }

}
```

ApplicationGroupUser Entity

```
public class ApplicationGroupUser
{
    public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationGroupId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ApplicationGroupId")]
    public ApplicationGroup ApplicationGroup { get; set; }

}
```

DbContext OnModelCreating :

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationGroup>()
            .HasMany(u => u.ApplicationGroupUsers);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationGroupUser>()
            .HasKey(r => new {r.ApplicationUserId, r.ApplicationGroupId});

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationGroup>()
            .HasMany(g => g.ApplicationGroupRoles);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationGroupRole>()
            .HasKey(gr => new { gr.ApplicationRoleId, gr.ApplicationGroupId});

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationGroupUser>().ToTable("ApplicationUserGroups");

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationGroupRole>().ToTable("ApplicationRoleGroups");

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationGroup>().ToTable("ApplicationGroups");
```

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new StatusCodeResult(400);
        }
        ApplicationGroup applicationgroup = _groupManager.Groups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == id);
        if (applicationgroup == null)
        {
            return new NotFoundResult();
        }
        var groupRoles = _groupManager.GetGroupRoles(applicationgroup.Id);
        var RoleNames = groupRoles.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
        ViewBag.RolesList = RoleNames;
        ViewBag.RolesCount = RoleNames.Count();
        return View(applicationgroup);
    }
```

View :

```
@model ApplicationGroup

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}
<h2>Details</h2>
<div>
    <h4>ApplicationGroup</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<h4>List of permissions granted this group</h4>
@if (ViewBag.PermissionsCount == 0)
{
    <hr />
    <p>No users found in this role.</p>
}
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.RolesList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Id }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

The result is when i got to the view, theres no roles, please help fix to fix this, where do i got wrong ?
[Screen Shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN47V.png)

**Update for solution:**

Need to change the controller to this :

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new StatusCodeResult(400);
    }
    var applicationgroup = _groupManager.Groups
            .Where(g => g.Id == id)
            .Select(g => new ApplicationGroup()
            {
                ApplicationGroupRoles = g.ApplicationGroupRoles
            }).FirstOrDefault();

    if (applicationgroup == null)
    {
        return new NotFoundResult();
    }
    var groupRoles = _groupManager.GetGroupRoles(applicationgroup.Id);
    var RoleNames = groupRoles.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
    ViewBag.RolesList = RoleNames;
    ViewBag.RolesCount = RoleNames.Count();
    return View(applicationgroup);
}
```

and need to change some query in other class to :

```
            var grp = _db.ApplicationGroups
            .Where(y => y.Id == groupId)
            .Select(g => new ApplicationGroup()
            {
                ApplicationGroupRoles = g.ApplicationGroupRoles
            })
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 is to check your database directly, and make sure that you have some `ApplicationGroupRole` rows that have an `ApplicationGroupId` that corresponds to the `Id` guid that can be seen in that screenshot.

If you do, then your problem *might* be that you're not including the `ApplicationGroupRoles` in your query.

To include your `ApplicationGroupRoles`, you can use the `Include` Extension method.   Make sure you have this using statement.

```
using System.Data.Entity
```

And then do your query like this

```
ApplicationGroup applicationgroup = _groupManager.Groups
    .Include(g => g.ApplicationGroupRoles)
    .FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == id);
```

---

Just a note:  You don't need `Include` statements, if you project your result onto a view model before you return from the db.  I.E.

```
var VM = _groupManager.Groups
    .Where(g => g.Id == id)
    .Select(g => new MyGroupViewModel()
    {
        Roles = g.ApplicationGroupRoles
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: already put data in ApplicationGroupRole, is there System.Data.Entity in asp.net core ? I cannot put include in the query, theres no option for include.

Comment: Yup, already read it, and Thank you very much! You save my day, work with the last statement, and i need to change all related query to that statement, updated to my first post

Answer (score 2):

In Identity 2 I did something similar to the group permissions project you referenced.  Except I named them Profiles instead of Groups.  I started to do the same thing in Identity Core but then realized there is a new Identity table named **UserRoleClaim** that I can use instead.  With this new table I accomplished the same thing without having to make modifications to the Identity Core database schema.  Also, I don't have to write my own EF code.  Everything can be done with the built-in methods in the `UserManager` and `RoleManager` classes.

You can equate a group to a role now.  Each role can have many claims and many users can belong to a role. The key to authorizing users is the claims that are related to the role(s) the user belongs to.  You cannot use the claims directly in the authorize attribute (that would be messy).  You have to associate claims to a policy.  **Policies are the awesomeness in Identity Core!**  They make it so you can organize your claims into profiles.  Then you only have to add a profile to your Authorize attribute.  Which is much better than adding a list of roles and/or claims like you had to in Identity 2.

The profiles are created with the `services.AddAuthorization()` method in the `ConfigureServices()` method of class Startup.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("Product", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Product"));
    options.AddPolicy("ProductEdit", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Product", "Edit"));
});
```

You can use these policies in an Authorize attribute.

```
[Authorize(Policy = "Product")]
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Policy = "ProductEdit")]
    public IActionResult Edit()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I would read up on Authorization in Identity Core before making any design decisions.  The documentation is actually pretty good and easy to read.  I suggest at least reading these articles.
[Claims-Based Authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html)
[Policy-Based Authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/policies.html)

I've described the basics of claims and policy based authorization in Identity Core.  But follow the rest of the articles in the documentation I linked to above and you will see that there are many more options available to you.

Comment: thanks for this, i'll look in to it. Is there any Github example for this ?

Comment: I couldn't find any.  But the documentation is good and it has plenty of examples.

Comment: Basically.  That was done in RC1 so things may be a littler different.  I created administration pages so a site administer can create roles by applying claims that I seed the database with to a role.  Then the administrator can assign roles to users.